# The basis of a subgroup $H \subset \mathbb Z^4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algorithms

Dear fellow mathstack exchangers,

There is a question in my Abstract Algebra syllabus I have trouble with solving, the main problem is is that there is no clear description of the algorithm I need. Sorry for my lack 
of initiative, but I don`t know where to start. Here is the question:

Find the basis for the subgroup $H \subset \mathbb Z^4$, given by 
$$H = \{ (a,b,c,d) \mid a + b + c + d = 0~~~\text{and}~~a \equiv c~~ (\bmod 12) \}$$

Thank you for the help!

PS: This is my first mathstack exchange post

Comment: $H = \{ (a,b,a+12e,-2a-b-12e) \mid a,b,e \in {\mathbb Z}\}$. Does that help?

Comment: Well, not really. I want to know the algorithm to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relations $a+b+c+d=0$ and $a=c \mod 12$ on $(a,b,c,d)$ can be written as $a+b+a+12e+d=0$ on $(a,b,a+12e,d)$.
In view of it  $g_1:=(1,0,1,-2), g_2:=(0,1,0,-1),$ and $ g_3:=(0,0,12,-12)$ form a basis  of [the module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29) $\mathbb{H}$.There are many other bases of $\mathbb{H}.$ PS. The set of the bases of $\mathbb{H}$ is infinite. I don't see any general algorithm to this end.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now! :)